# Why can I use Ok and Err directly without the Result:: prefix?

Tags: enums, rust

For example:

```
enum Foobar {
    Foo(i32),
    Bar(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let a: Result<i32, i32> = Result::Ok(1);
    let b: Result<i32, i32> = Ok(1);
    let c: Foobar = Foobar::Foo(1);
    let d: Foobar = Foo(1); // Error!
}
```

I have to write `Foobar::Foo()` instead of just `Foo()`, but I can just write `Ok()` without `Result::`. Why is that? I have the same question for `Some` and `None`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `use` item can add enum variants to a namespace, so that you don't have to prefix them by the enum's name.

```
use Foobar::*;

enum Foobar {
    Foo(i32),
    Bar(i32)
}

fn main() {
    let a: Result<i32, i32> = Result::Ok(1);
    let b: Result<i32, i32> = Ok(1);
    let c: Foobar = Foobar::Foo(1);
    let d: Foobar = Foo(1); // Not an error anymore!
}
```

The reason why `Ok`, `Err`, `Some` and `None` are available without qualification is that the [prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/v1/index.html) has some `use` items that add these names to the prelude (in addition to the enums themselves):

```
pub use option::Option::{self, Some, None};
pub use result::Result::{self, Ok, Err};
```